# Spring boot shared library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a microservice ecosystem as part of learning Spring Boot and I have some behavior that I expect to be shared across all the services in this ecosystem. I want this library to include some Spring behavior (e.g. event management, reading configs).

My initial problem was an `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration`, caused by there not being a main class (as expected, it's a library).

I've tried adding that annotation to my test class, adding it to a newly made class at a highest level of my package structure, and (as indicated in [this Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)) adding an internal class to my test class with the @SpringBootApplication annotation. In each case it clears up the error above, but fails to inject my beans.

In fact, when I cloned the repository for that Spring guide and added a second bean it was also no longer able to run the tests.

Comment: Please share your code snippet as well.

Comment: I've pushed the current WIP to github. 
https://github.com/pmeyerin/ProtocolSNPluginLib/tree/psn-7/autoregister